# Find by month seems to be missing files

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, find

I am running the following command to organize thousands of pictures, I've already created the  directory structure:

```
for YEAR in 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13; do
  for MONTH in Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec; do 
    echo $YEAR $MONTH; 
    find . -newermt "01-$MONTH-20$YEAR -1 sec" -and \
           -not -newermt "01-$MONTH-20$YEAR +1 month -1 sec" \
           -exec mv {} ../20$YEAR/$MONTH/ \; 
  done 
done
```

This has successfully moved several files already.  However, it seems find is missing files.  If I put an ll |wc -l after my script, there is still 2000 files in the directory.  If is sort by date, they're all created since January 2000.

I am not an expert at find. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `find . > allList; find . -newermt .... > dateList; comm -3 allList dateList` or similar might show you what is being missed, then it will be easier to understand what you need to change. Of course leave out the `-exec mv ..` on the 2nd `find` cmd. Oh, if all of your `dateList` files are already moved, then just `cd ../ ; find . > dateList` and then `comm ...` as before. The `cd ../` is meant to put you at the top of the dir that has all your 20$YEAR dirs. Good luck.

Comment: You wrote _they're all created since January 2000_ - but are they **modified** since 2000? (`-newermt` checks the modification time, not the creation or inode change time.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that uses OS X's stat and date:

```
for f in *;do d=../$(date -r $(stat -f%m $f) +%Y/%m);mkdir -p $d;mv $f $d;done
```

Use `date -d @$(stat -c%Y $f) +%Y/%m` with GNU stat and date.